# Artifactory docker-compose

Tags: docker, artifactory

Does anyone have a docker-compose.yml that starts up OSS version of Artifactory?
I am using file shown below but I see these errors when container starts up:

Errors:
**ArtifactoryClient::http [get] request to /api/system/ping failed with 404 code**
**ArtifactoryClient::http [get] request to /api/system/ping failed with 503 code**

When I try to access http://localhost:8081
my browser redirects to http://localhost:8082/ui/ and says This site can't be reached. localhost refused to connect.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  artifactory-service:
    image: docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-oss
    container_name: artifactory
    networks:
      - ci_net
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    volumes:
      - artifactory:/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory
      
volumes:
  artifactory:
networks:
  ci_net:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to this JFrog [wiki](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Installing+Artifactory#InstallingArtifactory-DockerComposeInstallation) on docker-compose installation and download the Artifactory-Oss tar from this [link](https://jfrog.com/download-legacy/?product=artifactory&installer=docker-compose). You might get the Artifactort-pro tar, download it and change the image to artifactory-oss in the docker-compose.yaml. One more thing, Artifactory oss if 7.x version then 8081 and 8082 ports should be opened.